# Converting string to XML in android?

Tags: android, xml, xml-serialization, xml-parsing, http-post

I am trying to convert data from database to XML in android. After that i am planning to post xml data to server using HttpPost?. But i am not sure how to convert string to xml in android.

I am looking for any sample code and methods.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found the solution here ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DOM from java library.

Refer:

http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse(java.lang.String)

http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.xml.parsers/BasicDom.html

Comment: Thanks for your comments.. I found the solution here ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html ... Thanks for your time